# Split on Split overlap [ RAKU ]

Tags: split, raku

I stumbled upon a "strange" behaviour when I tried to parse a multiline string (with tab separated strings) with the intent to find all values separated by tabs, using two splits in a row:

```
use v6.d;   # 2020.01 release

my $s = "L1:C1\tL1:C2\tL1:C3\nL2:C1\tL2:C2\tL2:C3\nL3:C1\tL3:C2\tL3:C3";

say $s.split(/\n/).split(/\t/).raku;
```

and the corresponding printout is as follows:

```
("L1:C1", "L1:C2", "L1:C3 L2:C1", "L2:C2", "L2:C3 L3:C1", "L3:C2", "L3:C3").Seq
```

The "strange" behaviour is in the 3d and 5th member of the resulting sequence. It seems that there is an overlap of the "expected" last string of a line and the first string of the subsequent line.

My expectation was something like :

```
("L1:C1", "L1:C2", "L1:C3", "L2:C1", "L2:C2", "L2:C3", "L3:C1", "L3:C2", "L3:C3").Seq
```

Anybody to give a detailed explanation to the innerworkings of this behaviour?

Just to clarify things, I know that the correct code is:

```
$s.split(/\n/)>>.split(/\t/).flat.raku
```

but my question is about the innerworkings of the "wrong" code. How did Raku come to that result?

Comment: If you're splitting on a literal, as an FYI, it's internally faster (or at least it used to be) to use a string for split (it doesn't have to take a regex): `$s.split("\n")».split("\t")` or, as lizmat mentions in the comments, `$s.lines>>.split("\t")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are splitting the result of the first split, which is a list; the split method will coerce whatever it's called on to a string and then splits it. A list will stringify (via its `Str` method) to its members separated by single spaces. That is the reason why some of the resulting fields have two L and C pairs and a space in between.

This will get you the result you want:

```
say "L1:C1\tL1:C2\tL1:C3\nL2:C1\tL2:C2\tL2:C3\nL3:C1\tL3:C2\tL3:C3"
    .split("\n")
    .map( *.split( "\t" ).Slip )
```

Since it splits the result of splitting the first, and then converts it into a [Slip](https://docs.raku.org/type/Slip) to get it *slipped* into the wider array.

Comment: Also: `$s.split(/\n/)` is probably better written as `$s.lines`

Answer (score 4):

If you would like your split to give you the individual pieces as one list, rather than a list of lists, you can use the split method's variant that takes a list of delimiters to split by:

```
say "L1:C1,L1:C2;L1:C3\nL2:C1-L2:C2|L2:C3^L3:C1".split([",", ";", "\n", "|", "^"]).raku;
# output: ("L1:C1", "L1:C2", "L1:C3", "L2:C1-L2:C2", "L2:C3", "L3:C1").Seq
```

Passing the `:k` or `:v` adverbs to the split method call will leave the separator in the result list as separate entries; with `:k` the value will be the index in the separators list that has the matched separator in it, with `:v` the separator itself will be in the result list.